# Convert string value to json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

```
        var chartData = @"  [ {name:'Russia',latLng: [59.7733,60.1853]}, {name:'United States',latLng: [37.3924,-121.9623]} ]";
 var newjson = JObject.Parse(chartData);
```

when i am going to parse above chartData in json object it gives me an error.
"Additional information: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 3."

anybody can help me please.

i have tried JObject.Parse()

Comment: Try surrounding the string values (e.g. 'Russia') and the keys (e.g. name) with double-quotes instead.

Comment: That is not valid JSON data. Please try reading the [specification](https://json.org) or a [tutorial](https://duckduckgo.com/q=json+tutorial). In JSON, quoted values must use `""` to quote.

Answer (score 2):

You have to sarround string values  and the keys  with double-quotes and since it is an array, use JArray instead of JObject

```
var chartData = @" [ {name:'Russia',latLng: [59.7733,60.1853]}, {name:'United States',latLng: [37.3924,-121.9623]} ]";

chartData=chartData.Replace("{name:","{\"name\":").Replace("latLng:","\"latLnq\":").Replace("'","\"");

var newjson = JArray.Parse(chartData);
```

or if you need this data for charts, it is better to deserialize it

```
List<ChartData> chartDatas = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChartData>>(chartData);

public class ChartData
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<double> latLnq { get; set; }
}
```